# Localizing django datepicker

Tags: django, localization, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using a jQuery UI datepicker with django. I managed to make the datepicker accept format of dd-mm-yyyy, but I'm not able to make the model accept it's data.

Any easy way to solve this?

Comment: Please provide the form definition, that you're using to render input.

Comment: You need to change your form field to accept that input - as @mariodev mentions, you need to post your form code.